# CloudKit zone not appears

Tags: xcode, core-data, cloudkit

I started a new project with Core Data and Cloud kit enabled (from Apple 2022 WWDC tutorial and Xcode 14.2) . I added a container. I synced a few data, sync is obviously working because I can delete the app and retrieve automatically all the data from the cloud.

My problem is that I can't see any data on the cloud kit portail. My requests don't return any object with public or private database[image], but I can confirm my entity is synced with its attributes. My guess is I'm seeing the wrong zone.

I read that the zone com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.zone should be selected in the Zone droplist but I never had this choice. In the Xcode console it confirms that the sync is done with this zone. Any clue how to get this option?

Comment: Make sure that you are using either development or production databases in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out : I used two different iCloud Apple ID (one with my dev account and App Store, one for Apple services and docs). You must use the same Apple ID on the device than the one with dev account. Apple should allow to merge accounts.